# Filling an array with a pointer to the array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 20
#define MIN 0
#define MAX 100

void FillArray(int *array, int size);
void PrintArray(int *array, int size);
void BubbleSort(int *array, int size);
void SelectionSort(int *array, int size);
void Swap(int *x, int *y);

int main() {
    int NumList[SIZE];
    int *array;
    array = NumList;
    FillArray(array, SIZE);
    PrintArray(array, SIZE);
}

void FillArray(int *array, int size) {
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++);  //<--- the K&R brace style would make this bug obvious!
    {
        *(array+i) = MIN + rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1);
    }
}

void PrintArray(int *array, int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf ("%d\n", array);
        array++;
    }
}
```

This program seems to be outputting random integers (not withing min and max) in increasing order, and I want to know why it's not random all the way through.
Specifically in the `FillArray` function. It seems to not be filling correctly.

Comment: `printf ("%d\n", array);` --> `printf ("%d\n", *array);`

Comment: Just gives a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no body to this loop

```
for (i=0; i<size; i++);
```

When it ends, the next line

```
*(array+i) =  MIN + rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1);
```

writes outside the bounds of the array.

Remove that semicolon...

```
for (i=0; i<size; i++)    // ---> ;
```

There is also the matter of

```
printf ("%d\n", array);
```

which should be

```
printf ("%d\n", *array);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! Wow... That's embarrassing.

Comment: Put the open brace on the same line as the `for`, `if`, `switch` and `while` statements to avoid this and other silly bugs.